# Sharing C++ static libraries between multiple solutions causes unnecessary rebuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have two solutions that both include and reference the same static library.  And I'm including the library using the "Add reference..." feature, as opposed to specifying additional an linker input.  It seems as though when I build one of the solutions, it causes the other solution to think it needs to rebuild the shared library, which then causes it to re-link the second solution.  Thus, if I go back and forth between the two solutions building (without making any code changes) the solutions perform the link every time.

It doesn't appear that the shared static library is actually being re-compiled, but VS is performing the librarian step for it.  I'm guessing this librarian step is happening because the .lastbuildstate file (which contains a path to the solution that last build the project) is determined to be outdated.

Anybody ever experienced this problem before?  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: If you have libX as a dependency on ProjA and ProjB, and you rebuild ProjA *with dependencies* (as opposed to building *only* ProjA, a selectable option if you right-click it in the solution explorer) it will rebuild libX as well, and thus cause a link dependency mismatch on ProjB. Thats just how VS works. Check how you're rebuilding ProjA or ProjB. Just selecting "Rebuild" will trigger the behavior your describing by-design.

Comment: Do you have any custom build step on the library by chance?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm just selecting the regular "build" to build the solution

Comment: @DarkWanderer No, don't have any custom build steps in the library or the referring solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library is really shared and independent from both solutions, I'd suggest moving it to a separate solution... I understand that's not really what you intended, but it seems logical by the nature of dependencies itself.

Another consideration in favor of this is that the library may be later used for other projects. Hence, it'd be totally better to move it to a separate location (separate solution, separate folder in VCS) and treat it as any third-party library (i.e. openssl, boost, etc), specifying the dependency as linker input.

All of the above is just my thoughts on how I'd do it and is not a representation of any "best practices".

Comment: Yeah, this is the route we had gone for previous projects of this sort, but I changed it because it seems easier to maintain (VS sets up the linker automatically) and it's convenient to have the library code right there with the project that's linking it in (e.g., "Go to Definition" works better).  And in fact, the library is currently in its own solution as well, so maybe I'll just switch back to the other style if the rebuilding becomes too annoying.